# want to get the Unique Value  MYSQL , ARRAY, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

We have a MySQL query, we used UNION ALL, We are getting two values for each table we just want to get only one single value, or we do one thing more, like we store the whole result into Array and then sort accordingly, then call the ID from array through Foreach loop

Here is the MYSQL query

```
  $num = mysql_query("(SELECT resorts.id From resorts,JUNE WHERE JUNE.id = resorts.id and JUNE.table_type = 'disp' AND JUNE.JUNE1!=0 AND resorts.category IN (1,2,3,4) AND resorts.area IN (1,2,3,4) Group By resorts.id LIMIT 0,7 ) UNION ALL (SELECT resorts.id From resorts,JULY WHERE JULY.id = resorts.id and JULY.table_type = 'disp' AND JULY.JULY1!=0 AND resorts.category IN (1,2,3,4) AND resorts.area IN (1,2,3,4) Group By resorts.id LIMIT 0,7 )");
```

We are getting the data like this ...

JUNE Table ID = 78 
JUNE Table ID = 124
JUNE Table ID = 11
JULY Table ID = 78
JULY Table ID = 124

We just want to do this time, we only get the single value for any Double ID. like if we are getting JUNE ID = 78 and we again getting the same ID for JULY ID = 78 .We just want to do the Unique list of (Double) id's and ignore the Single repeated id's . Like this 
JUNE Table ID = 78 
JUNE Table ID = 124

And ignore the rest of the id's,

**NOTE** :- our main motive is that, we only pass those id who are available in JUNE and JULY month, we ignore all the value if there are only in single months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `UNION ALL`, use `UNION`

Or make all your query into a subquery like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ($yourOldQueryHere)
```

Comment: unable to connect the Multiple queries.. Please help me to use the safely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your table structure or data but for retrieving Resort IDs that are available both in JUNE and JULY, you can use INNER JOIN between the 3 tables, like:

```
SELECT resorts.id
FROM resorts INNER JOIN JUNE ON resorts.id = JUNE.id
INNER JOIN JULY ON resorts.id = JULY.id
...
...
```

OR, if the above is not what you are looking for and you want to avoid duplicate IDs, use `UNION` instead of UNION ALL

Comment: Where we put the WHERE Clause in this query, IF we have month JUNE!=0 nad for JULY!=0 ... Please provide me the actual query with Where Clause..

Comment: Hi Rodger,

As I mentioned earlier, I'm not sure on the meaning of your tables and data, but you might try the below query and see if it works for you?

`SELECT resorts.id
FROM resorts INNER JOIN JUNE ON resorts.id = JUNE.id
INNER JOIN JULY ON resorts.id = JULY.id
WHERE JUNE.table_type = 'disp'
AND JULY.table_type = 'disp'
AND JUNE.JUNE1 != 0
AND JULY.JULY1 != 0
AND resorts.category IN (1,2,3,4)
AND resorts.area IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY resorts.id;`

Comment: Or instead this one:

SELECT resorts.id
FROM resorts INNER JOIN JUNE ON resorts.id = JUNE.id AND JUNE.table_type = 'disp' AND JUNE.JUNE1 != 0
INNER JOIN JULY ON resorts.id = JULY.id AND JULY.table_type = 'disp' AND JULY.JULY1 != 0
WHERE resorts.category IN (1,2,3,4)
AND resorts.area IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY resorts.id;